# very slow C#/linq loop need improvement suggestions

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following piece of code that I use to try to see if copying data from one table to an other missed some records.

There are reasons why this can happen but I won't go into the details here.

Now fortunately, this code runs against a few hundred records at a time, so I can allow myself lo load them into memory and use `LINQ` to Objects.

As I expected, my code is very slow and I'm wondering if anyone could suggest any way to improve the speed.

```
void Main()
{
    var crossed_data = from kv in key_and_value_table
                       from ckv in copy_of_key_and_value_table
                       where kv.key != ckv.key
                       select new { KeyTable = kv, copyKeyTable = ckv };


    List<Key_and_value> difference = new List<Key_and_value>();
    foreach (var v in crossed_data)
    {
        if (crossed_data.Select(s => s.Kv.key).ToList().
        Contains(v.ckv.Key) == false)
        {

            difference.Add(v.ckv);
        }
    }

}

public class Key_and_value
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

}
```

many thanks in advance
B

Comment: Why you did it manually, and didn't use `Except` extension method?

Comment: Try http://www.dotnetperls.com/except

Comment: I do it manually because those tables differ in many ways and there are other reasons why this can't be done through the  database. They just have a few columns in common. Anything will do. (extension method is fine)

Comment: Where is copyKeyTableImported defined?

Comment: You are producing a cartesian product X*Y: every row of key_and_value_table will be multiplied for every row of copy_of_key_and_value_table (plus other problems)

Comment: And now you have introduced something always true: crossed_data.Select(s => s. **copyKeyTable.key** ).ToList().Contains(v. **copyKeyTable.Key** ) clearly all the keys contains any one key :-)

Comment: `crossed_data.Select(s => s.copyKeyTable.key).ToList().Contains(v.copyKeyTable.Key)`  horrible in so many ways... :*( Edit: `cross_data.Any(s => s.copyKeyTable.key == v.copyKeyTable.Key)`  should be equivalent

Comment: What ever you can do in LINQ, I'm pretty sure you can do in the database, and it will be faster.

Comment: @CallumLinington: And then the OP will have +1 extra problems ;p

Comment: What is the purpose of the `s1` list?

Comment: @CallumLinington sure bu there are som other prior processing before the simplied version i presented here that are just more less error prone using linq, but i get the point.

Comment: @leppie s1 not relevant for my question. I tried to just show the essential here but have left overs from my real code. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing your `Select` every iteration when you do not need to. You can move it to the external scope like so.

```
var keys = crossed_data.Select(s=>s.ckv.key).ToList();

foreach(var v in crossed_data )
{
    if (keys.Contains(v.kv.Key) == false) 
    {
        difference.Add(v.Kv);
    }
}
```

This should improve the speed a fair bit.

Comment: This is still horribly inefficient

Comment: Or even `var keys = new HashSet<string>(crossed_data.Select(s=>s.copyKeyTable.key))`. HashSet.Contains is usually a lot faster than List.Contains. But is also a bit slower to create. So tests are needed to determine if one in this case outweighs the other.

Comment: @leppie It may well be pretty inefficient. The question asks for improvement suggestions, this is the simplest one. It will reduce the time by `(crossed_data.Count() - 1) * TimeToCreateListOfKeys`

Comment: Both those ideas are very clear improvement to my initial code and many thanks